# f# read xls file - how to parse a value2 object

Tags: c#, .net, excel, f#

I tried to use F# read a xls file as below

```
open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
let app = ApplicationClass(Visible = false)
let book = app.Workbooks.Open "test.xls"
let sheet = book.Worksheets.[1] :?> _Worksheet
let vals = sheet.UsedRange.Value2
```

The problem is how can I parse vals into a F# type? in fsx.exe, the vals showed as

```
'val vals: obj = [bound1
                  bound2
                  ["colname1"; "colname2"; ...]
                  [1234,5678,]...]
```

I wanted to retrieve the string represetation first, but 
`printfn "%A" vals.ToString();;` shows `"System.Object[,]"` only. If I then try to access `vals.[1,1]`, I got error `The field,constructor or member 'item' is not defined`

thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `Value2` is `obj`. If the range represents just a single cell, the actual type will be some primitive type (int, float, decimal, string). If the range represents several cells (your case), then the returned value is a two-dimensional .NET array of type `obj[,]`.

You can cast the value returned by `Value2` to an array and access it using indexers:

```
let vals = sheet.UsedRange.Value2 :?> obj[,]
vals.[1, 1]
```

Note that the returned array is 1-based (and not zero based as usual). The indexer again returns `obj`, so you need to cast the values to their actual type. Depending on your sheet, this will be probably float or string:

```
let firstTitle = vals.[1, 1] :?> string
let firstValue = vals.[2, 1] :?> float
```

(Assuming you have a title in A1 and a number in A2)

Comment: @matlabdbuser: Yes, I think that should work (because you're working with just plain .NET array). If you get a sub-range that contains only numbers, you can also convert it to 2D array of floats uing `Array2D.map float vals`.