# Import Excel data into F#

Tags: excel, f#

I would like to import some basic data (only few integers) from an Excel file into a F# list.
Here is the code I compute which open an Excel file, take the value of the Cell "C6" and 'store' it in a variable called l.
However it does not compiled as an type error appeared. Indeed type of first value is obj. 
How can I convert it into int?

```
//#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"

//#r "office"

open Microsoft.Office.Interop


let xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass()

let xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Users\Fabien C\Desktop\algo données.xlsx")

let xlWorkSheet = xlWorkBook.Worksheets.["Produits"] :?> Excel.Worksheet

let firstValue = xlWorkSheet.Cells.[6,3]

let (l : int) = firstValue
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [f# read xls file - how to parse a value2 object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031507/f-read-xls-file-how-to-parse-a-value2-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just add

```
:?> int
```

to the end of the last line to downcast firstValue, but see also the linked duplicate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031507/f-read-xls-file-how-to-parse-a-value2-object) for more on Excel interop.

Answer (score 1):

What is the real type of `firstValue`? If it's an int, use a dynamic cast:

```
firstValue :?> int
```

Otherwise maybe converting to a string and then an int would work:

```
firstValue |> string |> int
```