# F# Parse Excel File Into Tuple Array

Tags: excel, f#

I have a follow up question on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031507/f-read-xls-file-how-to-parse-a-value2-object) post.  I would like to take the contents of an Excel spreadsheet and put it into a Array of tuples where each tuple corresponds to each row in the spreadsheet.

I started with looping though the entire range like this:

```
    let path = "XXX.xlsx"
    let app = ApplicationClass(Visible = false)
    let book = app.Workbooks.Open path
    let sheet = book.Worksheets.[1] :?> _Worksheet
    let content = sheet.UsedRange.Value2 :?> obj[,]
    for i=content.GetLowerBound(0) to content.GetUpperBound(0) do
        for j=content.GetLowerBound(1) to content.GetUpperBound(1) do
```

But strikes me as very inefficient.  If there something in the base API spec out of the box that I can use?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The `Array2D` module implements some common functions for 2D arrays.

I am guessing you want to use `Array2D.iter` or `Array2D.iteri` to replace your for loop.

Comment: How do I create the tuple out of the values in each row?

Answer (score 0):

The straightforward way to convert each row (of a two-dimensional array) to a tuple (in a single-dimensional row) is to finish what you started - just iterate over all the rows and construct a tuple:

```
let tuples = 
  [ for i in contents.GetLowerBound(0) .. contents.GetUpperBound(0) -> 
      contents.[i,0], contents.[i,1], contents.[i,2] ]
```

To do this, you need to know (statically) what is the length of the row. This is because F# tuples are fixed-length tuples and the length is checked. The above example assumes that there are just 3 elements with indices `0`, `1` and `2`. If the length is dynamic, then you probably should continue using 2D arrays rather than a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to bypass the Excel engine altogether.  There are a couple of ways of doing this, but the one I've had great success with is 'SpreadsheetGear'.  It isn't free (bring on the downvotes), but it replicates the Excel API very closely and is very fast.